# Why do Delphi FireMonkey apps on Windows not share correctly with Microsoft Teams?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, microsoft-teams

I have a Delphi FMX app that runs on Windows (and only Windows). When I select the app using the "Share Content" feature in Microsoft Teams, I can select the app but nothing is actually shared. It just presents my team icon.

Any clues?

Comment: When I try to share FMX application built with Delphi 10.3 on my Windows 7 computer Windows disables the Aero desktop composition as if I would have be running some legacy DirectX based application. I'm guessing this is ude the fact that on Windows FireMonkey is rendering its contents on DirectX surface. But it is probably using old DirectX API.

Comment: As for some general advice on sharing content with Teams. I recommend you avoid sharing of individual applications. Why? Because when you chose share certain app Teams is only sharing the contents of the main window of such app. If your app opens a dialog box it won't be shared on teams as it is a new window. If your app shows hints they also won't be shared on teams since hints are shown by using of special Hint Windows. And they are many other issues that you can encounter. So I recommend using desktop sharing instead. Dual monitor setups are highly recommended for teams sharing.

Comment: Another way to successfully share your app on teams would be to make us of Capturing software like XSplit Broadcaster which is able to capture contents of FMX application perfectly and then broadcast that to other applications as camera source.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reaching out us. We are the developer support team for Microsoft teams focused on helping developers resolve their issues. For issues related to teams product, please reach out to the [product support channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/feedback#product-support-channels) for Microsoft Teams.